# Mysql: Select values(authors) from another table's list when creating/editing book table

Tags: php, mysql

It is pretty hard to explain what I need to do, but I was wondering if anyone is able to help me, I'm pretty new to Mysql and just started learning.
So I have 4 pages, book list and author list also add new author and new book. On of the tasks was when adding new book or edting, I can choose an author from author list to that book or just leave it empty. Using `<select><option></option></select>`

Created these 3 tables:

```
create table books(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(255),
    author_id integer,
    grade integer,
    is_read varchar(255) // when using bool, gives an error
);
```

```
create table author(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    grade integer
);
```

```
create table books_author(
    author_id integer,
    book_id integer
);
```

I've done this so far, but I'm still not able to choose author from the author list when adding or editing book data.

```
function getBooks()
{
    $connection = getConnection();
    $books = [];

    $getBooks = $connection->prepare("SELECT books.id, books.title, author.first_name, author.last_name,
    books.grade, books.is_read FROM books LEFT JOIN books_author INNER JOIN author ON
    books_author.author_id = author.id ON books.id = books_author.book_id WHERE title is not null ");
    $getBooks ->execute();
    foreach ($getBooks as $book) {
        $books[] = ["id" => $book['id'], "title" => urldecode($book['title']),"grade" => trim($book['grade']), "isRead" => trim($book['is_read'])];
    }
    return $books;
}
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN... ON...` is the normal syntax

Comment: Can you expand on "not able to" - what happens? That query doesn't look right to me - does it work without any errors if you execute it in phpmyadmin? Yes, as above, I think you've mixed your JOINs and stuck an extra one inside the first.

Comment: For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)